# An Operator Identity relating to Trace

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, eigenvalue

Suppose that $\hat H$ is an operator (typically a Hamiltonian) and $\beta$ is a positive parameter (typically $\beta=1/k_BT$). Show that
$$
\mathbf{Tr}\Big(e^{-\beta\hat H}\Big) \geq \sum_{k}e^{-\beta\langle k\vert\hat H k\rangle}
$$
My first step is using a Taylor expansion to yield
$$
\sum_{n}\frac{(-\beta)^n}{n!}\sum_{k}\Big(\langle k\vert\hat H^n\vert k\rangle-\big(\langle k\vert\hat H k\rangle\big)^n\Big)\geq 0
$$
How can I move forward?

Comment: What happens if $\{\vert k\rangle\}$ is an eigenbasis of $\hat{H}$?

Comment: Starting from the very first expression in the question, literally write out the definition of the trace...

Comment: @nephente: If ${\vert k \rangle}$ happen to be eigenbasis of $\hat H$, the "=" holds.

Comment: What's is the properties of your k's?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21420/2451